# Setq org-agenda-files in Windows

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-agenda, microsoft-windows

I'm just looking to add files to my org-agenda-variable. I added a single file successfully but am unable to use multiple.

With the code below in my `.emacs.el` file, the agenda buffer shows 0 TODO's despite there being plenty in the files specified.

Am I using `list` wrong?

Per another question I checked and the code is not in the `customize` block.

```
(setq org-agenda-files (list "C:/Users/Hugh/Documents/CS/Org/todo_dissertation.org"
    "C:/Users/Hugh/Documents/CS/Org/todo_LT_misc.org"
    "C:/Users/Hugh/Documents/CS/Org/todo_ST_misc.org"
    "C:/Users/Hugh/Documents/CS/Org/todo_career.org"))
```

`C-h v user-init-file` gives:

```
Its value is "c:/Users/Hugh/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.el"
```

which is the file I'm editing.

`M-x emacs-version` returns:

```
GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86-64-w64-mingw32) of 2018-05-30
```

`M-x org-version` returns:

```
Org mode version 9.1.9 (release-9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ c:/Users/Hugh/emacs/share/emacs/26.1/lisp/org/
```

Comment: Your usage of `list` is fine. What does `M-:` `(mapcar #'file-readable-p org-agenda-files)` say? (It should say `(t t t t)`.)

Comment: nice, it says `nil`. I wasn't sure what to do without an error message.  Must be a problem with one or more of the `.org` files?

Comment: ok thanks, that was a typo but not an issue with the actual file

Comment: Get the help for the variable `user-init-file` with `C-h v` `user-init-file` `RET`. I guess you put `.emacs.el` into your user directory but emacs expects the init file in some `roaming` directory. You can avoid that by setting the `HOME` environment variable.

Comment: hmm, maybe but I've successfully made other changes to the init file, and its saved in `C:/Users/Hugh/AppData/Roaming` so should be correct.

Comment: It was only a guess motivated by the the `nil` value for `M-:` `(mapcar #'file-readable-p org-agenda-files)`. That value indicates that `org-agenda-files` is not set at all. If the files failed to exist or failed to be readable you would get `(nil nil nil nil)`. Does the help for `user-init-file` say `C:/Users/Hugh/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.el`? If that is right please put a note about it into your question (maybe at the end). I think that might help others.

Comment: Put the following `defmacro` before your `setq`, change the `setq` into a `setq-loudly`, and tell us what the message buffer says about `org-agenda-files`: ``(defmacro setq-loudly (&rest var-val-seq) "Set like `setq' the VAR-VAL-SEQ sequence and emit message." (append '(progn) (cl-loop for var-val on var-val-seq by 'cddr collect `(message "(setq %s %S)" (quote ,(car var-val)) (setq ,(car var-val) ,(cadr var-val)))) (last var-val-seq 2)))``. Add a not about the result to your question. I can also add the nicely formated macro to your question.

Comment: State the result of `M-x emacs-version` and `M-x org-version` in your question. (There are [new powerful debug tools](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Debugging.html) in recent versions of Emacs.)

Comment: Put `(debug-on-variable-change 'org-agenda-files)` before the form `(setq org-agenda-files ...)` and restart Emacs. We expect at least one time a Backtrace buffer poping up when `org-agenda-files` is set to the list of strings. You can continue execution by typing `c` into the Backtrace buffer. If the Backtrace buffer pops up a second time you can see in the call stack printed in the Backtrace buffer where `org-agenda-files` is set back to nil. When you do not get a Backtrace buffer that indicates that the code fragment including `org-agenda-files` is not executed at all.

Comment: awesome yes there was a line in `(custom-set-variables '(org-agenda-files nil))`.

Comment: Please post the final resolution as an answer and accept it. That will make the question (and answer) more useful to future browsers (people, not programs :-)).

Comment: I'll put the debug steps into an answer in the next couple days if Tobias doesn't want to bother :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I debugged this:

first, use `C-H v user-init-file RET` to check the location of the `init` file. There's a chance the wrong file is being edited.

Then use `M-: (mapcar #'file-readable-p org-agenda-files)` to check the status of the files listed in the `org-agenda-files` variable. If they're readable, the expression returns `(t t)` where there is a t for each readable file in the list.

Then, use the `setq-loudly` function to check the value of the `org-agenda-files` as emacs is initialized when emacs is restarted.

```
(defmacro setq-loudly (&rest var-val-seq) 
    "Set like `setq' the VAR-VAL-SEQ sequence and emit message." 
    (append '(progn) (cl-loop for var-val on var-val-seq by 'cddr collect 
        `(message "(setq %s %S)" (quote ,(car var-val)) (setq ,(car var-val) ,
            (cadr var-val)))) (last var-val-seq 2)))
```

finally, use `(debug-on-variable-change 'org-agenda-files)` in the `init` file. This will offer a debug buffer each time the variable is changed.

In my case, the init file called `(setq org-agenda-files 'list( "path-string"))` twice. Once where I added and edited it and once where `customize` had added it, setting it to `nil`